# How to get only div with id ending with a certain value in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have  a webpage source where it has so many div with their respective id .

For example:

```
<div id="abc_answer">Some content</div>
<div id="abcd_answer">Some content</div>
<div id="ggg">Some Content</div>
```

I would like to extract only information which has "_answer" substring in id of all given div. I would like to do this with beautifulsoup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(some.text, "html.parser");
found = bsObj.findAll("div", id=lambda x: x and x.endswith('_answer'))
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the [`.select()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and pass in the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[id$=_answer]` which will select elements with an `id` attribute value ending with the substring `_answer`:

```
soup.select('div[id$=_answer]')
```

Output:

```
> [<div id="abc_answer">Some answer</div>, <div id="abcd_answer">Some answer</div>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `find_all` that can do any kind of checks:

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag:    tag.name=='div' \
                         and tag.has_attr('id') \
                         and tag['id'].endswith("_answer")))
#[<div id="abc_answer">Some content</div>, 
# <div id="abcd_answer">Some content</div>]
```

Make sure you check that the `id` exists before looking at its value.